# Percent of change?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I'm a GIS student and my task is to map, at the county level, the growth in elderly population between 2000 and 2010 (as a proportion of total population) for Louisiana and to compare the pattern of growth to growth in the elderly population at the state level across the nation. So, two maps—one of the entire U.S., state level, and the other for Louisiana, county level.

The variable I'm trying to map is:

Change in Elderly =    Elderly2010/Total_Pop2010 - Elderly2000/Total_Pop2000

I'm trying to map the percent of change.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What data have you got? Data of U.S. states shouldn't be difficult but you'll need census data and then the census blocks that they relate to.

Comment: I have 2000 and 2010 census tracts data. I'm sure I need more.

Comment: Do you have counties, states? Please edit your question with the data at hand. I'm not familiar with U.S. census (I'm in Australia) but it should be fairly similar.

Comment: I do have the Louisiana counties and states both POP2000. I need to acquire 2010 population data and figure out how to map the percent of change.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

This outlines the basic principles of overlaying data and is intended only as a guide:

If the U.S. census data is anything like the Australian census data the population/age is split into deciles so you will want to isolate what's elderly.. 70-80,80-90,90+ from the census (probably in excel) and sum them up to Elderly and total population. Be sure to keep the census link id (the common value between table and census tracts). It is a *very good idea* to make it Elderly00, Pop00, Elderly10 and Pop10 for 2000 and 2010 data respectively.

Join using [add join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000064000000) to get the tabular data onto the census tracts and [export](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000035000000) to lock in the values (optional).

To compare one with the other (assuming census blocks change) express your elderly as a percent (Elderly / TotalPop) using [Add Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000047000000) and [Calculate field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Calculate_Field/00170000004m000000/) and then overlay the old with the new using [Identity](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000n000000), [intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Intersect/00080000000p000000/) or [union](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Union/00080000000s000000/) - I'd use union but it might cause sliver polygons that could be annoying later.

After overlay you will have lots of fields from both feature classes, among which is a elderly population percent for each of 2000 and 2010. I'll let you decide how to express your change; for your maths you will need to extrapolate back to population using the areas of the intersected polygons - for which you would need to calculate the density originally and then expand after intersect.

Comment: Could you accept the answer. A warning: joining to Excel is asking for trouble. It is best to import the sheet with the data into a database (.mdb, .dbf..) or do the field calculations in ArcMap.

Comment: You're welcome. By accept I meant click the little tick under the answer to say that this answer helped. This takes the thread out of the unanswered questions list and shows users in the future which answer helped. It also gives you some reputation points (3 I think) and a bronze badge for accepting your first answer.